# Regular expression for math formula?

Tags: php, regex

As i am new to reg ex and php i am creating math formula maker but i stuck in to validating that formula. I am able to validate brackets matching through php code but not exact operator. Can any one help me to write regular expression to validate it?

I have formula e.g `A1+500+4`
but it is taking input as `A1++5%/` like this

i am validating barket using lexical analysis an simple formula by reg ex as follow

```
([A0-9][-+%~^*]\d+(\.\d+)?)
```

Comment: Please, post your current regular expression.

Comment: i am validating barket using lexical analysis an simple formula by reg ex as follow ([A0-9][-+%~^*]\d+(\.\d+)?)

Comment: You don't want a regex, you want a lexer. Parse the input and make sure everything is as expected.

Comment: i did that using parser but i am not able to validate operators using it

Comment: it is still taking formula as A1++(10+20) like this

Comment: What is the context where matches are expected? Try [`(?<!\S)A[0-9]+(?:[-+%~^*]+\d+(?:\.\d+)?)+(?!\S)`](https://regex101.com/r/gyI1tv/1).

Comment: but it is taking input as A1++5%/

Comment: i want  A1+100-A5 like this

Comment: Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/gyI1tv/2)?

Comment: Well done!!!THANKS

Comment: Ok, added as an answer with explanations.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
(?<!\S)A[0-9]+(?:[-+%~^*]+A?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)+(?!\S)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gyI1tv/2)

**Details**

- `(?<!\S)` - a negative lookbehind that requires no non-whitespace immediately before the current location (there must be a whitespace or start of string right before the current location, a leading whitespace boundary)
- `A[0-9]+` - `A` followed with 1+ digits
- `(?:[-+%~^*]+A?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)+` - one or more occurrences of

  - `[-+%~^*]+` - 1+ `-`, `+`, `%`, `~`, `^` or `*` chars
  - `A?` - 1 or 0 `A`s
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional sequence of

    - `\.` - a dot
    - `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?!\S)` - a negative lookahead that requires no non-whitespace immediately after the current location (there must be a whitespace or end of string right after the current location, a trailing whitespace boundary)